# Use locking macro or monitor-enter and monitor-exit in Java from Clojure

Tags: java, clojure, locking

I have a piece of Clojure code need to optimize for better performance. My thought is to rewrite it using java. There is one object I used locking macro in the code that I need to rewrite and this object may also be locked else where which is written in Clojure code.

I don't want to define new ReentrantLock object because this application is memory sensitive.

My question is what in java is equal to locking macro, or `monitor-enter` and `monitor-exit` under the hood from Clojure?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the following Clojure code:

```
(def someObject ...)

(locking someObject
  ;; critical section)
```

where `locking` is a macro translating to:

```
(let [lock someObject]
  (try
    (monitor-enter lock)
    ;; critical section
    (finally
      (monitor-exit lock))))
```

Java's equivalent is `synchronized` keyword:

```
Object someObject = ...;
synchronized (someObject) {
    // critical section
}
```

Or another form synchronizing on `this` reference:

```
public synchronized void someMethod() {
    // critical section
}
```

which is equivalent to:

```
public void someMethod() {
    synchronized (this) {
        // critical section
    }
}
```

You can also synchronize on class object:

```
public class SomeClass {
    public static synchronized void someMethod() {
        // critical section
    }
}
```

which is equivalent to:

```
public class SomeClass {
    public static void someMethod() {
        synchronized (SomeClass.class) {
            // critical section
        }
    }
}
```

Java's `synchronized` keyword is compiled into JVM's `monitorenter` and `monitorexit` bytecode instructions. Clojure's `monitor-enter` and `monitor-exit` special forms use the same bytecode instructions.